# How to name documents in windows?

Tags: filesystems

What is the best way to name documents and folders in windows? Im thinging about maybe there will be some conflict in some programs? Or when searching in terminal

This_Is_Best.doc

ThisIsBest.doc

This Is Best.doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx

i hope this'll help.